# Expect.pm to login to a router and execute a command

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I'm trying to login to the router and execute a command. I'm able to do it with `Net::ssh::Perl`. But I'd like to use perl `Expect.pm` instead of `Net::ssh::Perl`. Can some one tell me how to do the following steps with expect.pm ?

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Net::SSH::Perl;

    my $host     = "ip";
    my $password = "password";
    my $user    = "user";

    $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
    $ssh->login($user, $password);

    # Get into config terminal prompt 
    $ssh->cmd("configure terminal");

   # Execute the command   
    my $cmd = $ssh->cmd("show crytpo session");
    print($cmd);
```

Comment: Best option for linux would be https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH module.

Comment: @Сухой27 I'm asked to use Expect.pm .